# sharepoint 2010 sitemap duplicate node urls

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sitemap

Is there any way at all to disable a link on a node?

For example, I would like to disable the "Dashboards" menu item/node, ie, clicking on it on the site will do nothing.

Is this possible?

thanks,

KS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap>
<siteMapNode title="" url="">
<siteMapNode title="BI Home" url="/Home.aspx"/>
<siteMapNode title="Scorecards" url="/Scorecards.aspx">
  <siteMapNode title="Performance Scorecard" url="/Perfomance-Card.aspx"/>
  <siteMapNode title="Quality Scorecard" url="/Quality-Card.aspx"/>
  <siteMapNode title="Service Scorecard" url="/Service-Card.aspx"/>
  <siteMapNode title="Financial Operations Scorecard" url="/FinancialOps-Card.aspx"/>
</siteMapNode>
<siteMapNode title="Dashboards">
  <siteMapNode title="Executive Dashboard" url="/Executive-Dash.aspx"/>
  <siteMapNode title="Operational Scorecard" url="/Operational-Card.aspx"/>
</siteMapNode>
<siteMapNode title="Manual Entry">
  <siteMapNode title="Labor Hours" url="/Labor-Hours.aspx"/>
  <siteMapNode title="Lost Time Accidents" url="/Lost-Time-Accidents.aspx"/>
  <siteMapNode title="Action Items" url="/Action-Items.aspx"/>
  </siteMapNode>
  <siteMapNode title="Reports" url="/Reports.aspx"/>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I settled for second best. What is second best?

Well, I set the main menu item to the same url as the first option beneath it.

But you cannot have duplicate urls in the sitemap nodes I hear you say!

Bypassed this by appending a querystring parameter to the end of the url.

I changed dashboards like so:

```
<siteMapNode title="Dashboards" url="/Executive-Dash.aspx?S=1"/>
```

Not very elegant but it is acceptable for my sce